# Azure app openid connect issue with azure ad login in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have enabled the Authentication / Authorization setting which Authentication Providers is Azure Active Directory . After config i could sign in the app , but when i enter /.auth/me endpoint , i only find the id_token , how to access a api (graph api for example) like what i have done with openid connect owin in c# in code sample microsoft provide .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to call Graph API with Authentication / Authorization feature :

1. In azure portal , click [Azure Active Directory]-->[App registrations] ,find the app registered in azure ad:
   [image]
2. click that app ,showing the [setting] blade , you could create `Keys` and click `Required permissions`  , you could set/grant required permissions for the api , in your scenario , you should add the graph api you want to call (not sure you want to call microsot graph api or azure ad graph api) .
3. Using a tool ： [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) , search for your web, mobile or API app using the search bar,navigate to /config/authsettings ,add the `clientSecret` you config in previous step .Modify the `additionalLoginParams` to use code flow and specify the resource :

   "additionalLoginParams": ["response_type=code id_token",resource=https://graph.windows.net"],
   I use azure ad graph api and you could modify the `resource` for the api you want to call :
   [image]
4. Save your changes (first click EDIT, modify the config , the click PUT ) .
5. The next time users log into your web app , afther user consent , you would find the access token when redirect to /.auth/me endpoint .