# ADAL plugin for Cordova: ability to receive the authorization code in addition to the token

Tags: cordova, azure, adal

This is about the "Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) plugin for Apache Cordova apps" (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova).

Here's my problem:

After a successful login, the "acquireTokenAsync" method of the Cordova plugin gives me a response containing (among others) the id_token and the access_token.

This is cool, but is there a way to receive the authorization code (in addition to the token) ?

What I mean is that, if you're implementing the AzureAD/OAuth authentication flows in a web app (browser based), it's possible to simply append a "response_type" parameter to your "authorize" URL. Using this "response_type" parameter, you can specify what kind of data you want to receive back in your redirect-URL (after successful login):

```
response_type="token"
response_type="code"
response_type="code id_token"
```

etcetera (for info see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code).

So, what I would like is to specify a response_type of "code token" or "code id_token". Is something like this possible with the Cordova plugin?

I've searched high and low but no joy.

The only option that looked promising was the "extraQueryParameters" parameter of the "acquireTokenAsync" method, I tried this but that didn't yield the desired outcome (I received an error that the "response_type" parameter was already set, apparently I can't override an existing URL param this way, only add new ones).

There seems to be no way to set or override "response_type", or is there?

(one way might be to modify the Azure AD app configuration in the Azure Portal, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43675721)

Comment: Why do you need the authorization code? Aren't Cordova apps essentially native apps? Would you be able to store a client secret securely in the app so that no one can get access to it?

Comment: Good question, yes I didn't explain why I want it. The reason is my backend dev says he needs it to query the Graph API to get the user's email, which can be different from the "upn" that you can get from the access token.

In the meantime I've found another and more promising route to get the user's email:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808409/how-to-get-email-address-from-azure-ad-b2c-authentication

This means changing the Azure AD app's configuration, and adding "email" to the "scope" parameter which can be done via the "extraQueryParameters" argument of "acquireTokenAsync".